# jQuery: how to validate at leat one of two field

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

In my form there two fields whose ids are "partita_iva" and "codice_fiscale". I need that al least one of them is not empty. So, looking in stackoverflow I found the following:

```
codice_fiscale: {
        required: "#partita_iva:empty",
        remote: {
            url: "include/utils/checkCliente.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id: id_cliente,
                cf_ck: function() {
                    return jQuery("#codice_fiscale").val();
                }
            }
        }
    },

    partita_iva: {
        required: "#codice_fiscale:empty",
        remote: {
            url: "include/utils/checkCliente.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id: id_cliente,
                piva_ck: function() {
                    return jQuery("#partita_iva").val();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And messages are

```
codice_fiscale: {
        remote: "Codice fiscale già esistente!",
        required: "Inserisici il codice fiscale del cliente privato",
    },

    partita_iva: {
        required: "Inserisci la partita IVA del cliente",
        remote: "Partita IVA già esistente!",
    },
```

So if both are empty I get correctly the error message for both. Unfortunately, if I fill either "`codice_fiscale`" or "`partita_iva`" then I still get the error message for the other field...Where am I making the mistake?

**SOLUTION:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

codice_fiscale:{

 //required: true, 
 required: function(element) {
             return !jQuery("#partita_iva").is(':filled'); /***/
           },
...
}

partita_iva:{

 //required: true, 
 required: function(element) {
             return !jQuery("#codice_fiscale").is(':filled'); /***/
           },
...
}
```

NB: in line with /***/ use

```
:filled
```

because

```
:empty
```

(as I did before) does not work and it is discuraged to use.

Comment: Are you using some sort of validation plug-in?

Comment: this:       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method